# socket.io in Jmeter

Tags: socket.io, jmeter

I studied a sample from this link http://socket.io/docs/

Example

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>        
<script>

  var socket = io('ws://127.0.0.1:3000');
  socket.emit('ui:index:loaded',{_id: '123456'});

  socket.on('app:banner:loaded',function(obj){
      console.log(obj);
  });

  socket.on('app:collection:loaded',function(obj){
      console.log(obj);
  });

</script>
```

How to use this in Jmeter?

Now, I request 2probe, it response 3probe.

I need to send event

[image]

Anyone have ideas.

Answer (score 2):

There is a super late answer for anyone still needs it.

I used Chrome dev tools and tried to see what happened when a event emitted. I found that there was a http POST request sent when emitting event, so what I did was creating a same http request by jmeter, and it works.

In my case, the event name is "join", and the content is
{"sn":"1522729528413MDSCDGE","vsn":"093"}

Here is what I've found in [Chrome's Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1fbm.png)

And here is a [HTTP Request Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz70g.png) I created by jmeter.

I think the number 52 means the string length of your event content. If you want to change your event content, remember to calculate a correct length, and I don't know what 42 means. I just copied it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't support WebSocket testing out-of-the-box, you will need either to use the plugin or to write some code in [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

If you want to go the "plugin way":

1. Download and install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
2. From JMeter main menu select `Options -> Plugins Manager -> Available Plugins -> Websocket Protocol Support`

   [image: Websocket protocol support]
3. After the plugin installation you should be able to add the WebSocket Sampler. Appropriate configuration will look like:

   - Server Name or IP: `localhost`
   - Port Number: `3000`
   - Protocol: `ws`
   - Request Data: `{_id: '123456'}`

   [image: WebSocket Sampler Configuration]

   You will also need to add some form of expected response into the "WebSocket Response" stanza.

See [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) guide for more information on using the plugin and manually sending WebSocket messages via Groovy code.

Comment: I tried request 2probe , it response 3probe but how to send event (socket.emit) in Jmeter